# R: Combine expression,atop and line break

Tags: r

Do you have any idea how to combine multiple lines with `expression` and `atop`? I Mean I use this:

```
library(Gmisc)
library(glue)
box <- boxGrob(expr(atop(bold("1. My First Step"), italic("This is a very long text that needs \n a line break"))))
```

This results in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix the overlapping lines, you could use `glue` like this:

```r
library(Gmisc)
library(glue)
boxGrob(glue("1. My First Step",
             "This is a very long text that needs \n a line break",
             tot = 30,
             uninterested = 12,
             contra = 30 - 12,
             .sep = "\n"),
        just = "left")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I am only not sure how to implement bold and italic in this.

Comment: This was my first version :) But yes - I also did not manage to combine this with bold and italic that's why I did the approach with expression